# Use react-query mutation get axios error 415

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

I have detail page use for edit data. At first i use yup and simple function to call api.
This is my first code.

**CustomerEditPage.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useMutation, useQueryClient, useQuery } from 'react-query'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup'
import * as yup from "yup"
import * as api from '../../../service/CustomerDescApi'


const schema = yup.object({
    customerCode: yup.string().required('Customer Code is a required field'),
    taxid: yup.string().required('Tax Id is a required field'),
    nameLocal: yup.string(),
    nameEng: yup.string(),
    address1: yup.string(),
    address2: yup.string(),
    refCompany: yup.string(),
    comCus: yup.string(),
    // status: yup.string(),
  //   createddate: new Date()
  
  }).required()
  
  const updateCustomer = async (cvid,newdata) => {
    const response = api.UpdateCvdesc(cvid,newdata);
    return response
}

const CustomerEditPage = () => {
const CVID = location.state.ID

const { register, handleSubmit, formState:{ errors }, setValue } = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(schema)
    })

setValue('customerCode', customer.customerCode)
    setValue('taxid', customer.taxid)
    setValue('nameLocal', customer.nameLocal)
    setValue('nameEng',customer.nameEng)
    setValue('address1',customer.address1)
    setValue('address2',customer.address2)
    setValue('refCompany',customer.refCompany)
    setValue('comCus',customer.comCus)
    setValue('status',customer.status)



    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        updateCustomer(CVID,data)
    }
```

**CustomerDescApi.js**

```
import axios from "axios"

export const MRCAPI = axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://localhost:7257",
      headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" ,
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
})

export const UpdateCvdesc = async (cvid,newdata) => {
   console.log(newdata)
   const response = await MRCAPI.put(`/TestCustomerDesc/${cvid}`, newdata)
   return response.data
}
```

Now i want to use react-query in my project, So i add code mutation to this page.

**CustomerEditPage.js ( React-Query )**

```
 const { mutate } = useMutation(updateCustomer, {
        onSuccess: data => {
          console.log(data);
          const message = "Update Success"
          alert(message)
        },
        onError: () => {
          alert("there was an error")
        },
        onSettled: () => {
          queryClient.invalidateQueries('update');
        }
    })
```

I change onSubmit form function.

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
      mutate(CVID,data)
      //updateCustomer(CVID,data)
      }
```

After use react-query i always get error 415 bad-request from axios. But when i remove react-query code it work find. So i don't know what cause error.

Comment: do you think adding await in "updateCustomer" could help

Comment: I try it still error